# Python: multiple qqplot in statsmodel

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I'm new to python. At moment, I'm trying to do qqplot in statsmodels, with data from a csv file. No idea on how to upload data file, so I capture part of it as picture. [Here is the head part ofdata from csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xGl2.png). 
I want to plot multiple qqplots on one page with 2x2 style, but cannot get the plots correct. Having done much research, I think if it would be much helpful if people could give me some hints or tell me where the problem is.

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import scipy.stats as scs
    import statsmodels.api as sm
    from pylab import plt
    plt.style.use('ggplot')
    import matplotlib as mpl

    symbols = ['SPY', 'GLD', 'AAPL.O', 'MSFT.O']
    raw = pd.read_csv('tr_eikon_eod_data.csv',
                    index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
    data = raw[symbols]
    data = data.dropna()
    log_returns = np.log(data / data.shift(1))


    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(6,4))
       for sym in symbols:
          sm.qqplot(log_returns[sym].dropna(),line='s',ax=ax[sym])


    plt.grid(True)
    plt.xlabel('theoretical quantiles')
    plt.ylabel('sample quantiles')
    plt.title(sym)

    plt.show
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRLzz.png)
apparently I cannot review the picture I have uploaded

Answer (score 0):

This will create 2by2 plot (2 rows, 2 columns), haven't figured out how to add title for each plot tough. Basecially, take advantage of matplotlib.pyplot.figure properties.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pylab

figure, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10,8))

sm.qqplot(df.col_name1, line='s', ax = axes[0, 0])
sm.qqplot(numpy.ndarray, line='s', ax = axes[0, 1])
sm.qqplot(series3, line='s', ax = axes[1, 0])
sm.qqplot(df.col_name2, line='s', ax = axes[1, 1])
figure.suptitle('Multiple qq plots', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
#pylab.show()
```